# Interacting with a Google Cloud Bucket from an Independent PHP Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have a `VPS Server` running `Ubuntu`, `NGINX` and `PHP`. However, as this server has little storage, I want to use a Google Cloud Storage bucket to store user-uploaded images for my websites. Setting up and interacting with the GCS bucket through Google's console has been fine and I have had few problems. However, I can find no documentation on how to interact with the GCS from an independent server with PHP, though there is a large amount of information on how to interact with it using AppEngine. From my research, it appears that a lot of other people have had my problem but I have, as yet, not found any tutorials on the operations I need to do.

For the website I am working on I need to:

- Upload image files from my server to a GCS bucket (there would be no
  interaction with the client)
- Selectively delete files from the GCS bucket.

Although anything else would be useful.

The closest help articles I could find were [this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload), which provides information about AppEngine and [this one](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples), which, besides many other problems that I went through fixing, just doesn't seem to work.

It is impossible to pay for a support plan.

Comment: I'm also still learning about this, but if I understand correctly interacting with GC Storage from an AppEngine instance (or for that matter any VM on GCP) is a bit different then doing so with a server not in GCP. Things like authentication are configured automatically in GC VM's, so you'll have to do that manually in other servers. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started-gsutil) to interact with google cloud storage buckets and storage from command line. Or you can download google cloud sdk and interact via PHP following the article you shared.

Here is another article about [using gsutil](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-storage-tutorial-part-1-aee81f9d3247#.6zidpkayw)